# Brand/Categorie listing on a custome cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree

I like to do the follow issue:

A **custom CMS pag**e - calling landingpage for each brands we have.

On this page we will have some images, some listing for featured products and a listing from all categories, exist in a specific brand. So for example:

We have the brand Puma:

In there all products by Puma, splitted up in different **categories**, eg

1. Men
   -> Men Running Shoes
   -> Men Trekking Shoes

   - Women
   - Running Shoes
   - Appareils
   - Clothes men
   - Clothes Women

etc.

Does it have an extension for it, or what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is free extension available for that

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-splash-pages.html

> Note:: I am not promoting this extension,i had used this extension
>   before and it works like fine and also free extension

Comment: Thank You... I installed... and I tried to use it... but I didn't get what I want.

Even I tried to find some document or so... nothing found.